# Remove folder & files from project using NuGet/Powershell

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to remove the App_Start folder from my project during my NuGet package install. The documentation for NuGet here:

http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20Package

Says:

> $project.Object is the equivalent of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170626.aspx.

Which I am not able to find much information of that interface that is of much help to me.

I have the following Powershell script which successfully **removes** the folder and files:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$DirInfo = New-Object System.IO.DirectoryInfo($installPath) 
$appDir = New-Object System.IO.DirectoryInfo($DirInfo.Parent.Parent.FullName)
$fullPath = [IO.Path]::Combine($appDir.FullName, $appDir.Name, "App_start")
Remove-Item $fullPath -recurse
```

(I know the pathing here isn't guaranteed, but this package is for internal use only)

But the project still has a reference to the items and therefore the items appear with the yellow warning because Visual Studio believes that the items are part of the project.

What I need is a way to remove a reference to those items from the project programatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, I'm absolutely sure there's a better way than this, but I've never used NuGet or Powershell until today... :/

I just ran this in my Package Manager Console:

```
$DTE.Solution.Projects | ForEach { $_.ProjectItems | ForEach { if ($_.Name -eq "Controllers") { $_.Remove() } } }
```

It looped through all projects items looking for a top-level item called "Controllers" and then removed it from the project. Pretty sure you could just change this to "App_Code".

Edit: Friend of mine (who knows a little more Powershell than me) sent this:

```
$DTE.Solution.Projects|Select-Object -Expand ProjectItems|Where-Object{$_.Name -eq 'Controllers'}|ForEach-Object{$_.Remove()}
```

Comment: In PowerShell, when you have `... | foreach { $_.Foo | % { ... } }` you can usually write `... | foreach { $_.Foo } | % { ... }` - you don't have to nest the `foreach`s.

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty new to PoSh when I wrote this. It works, but it can probably be made much more readable =D

Comment: Did not know that I could browse the solution directly in the PM console via $DTE.Solution.xyz commands. Thank you, this sped up my job!